# How to detect Selenium?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my PHP application I'd like to detect requests that are for Selenium tests. Mainly because I'd like to use a separate database for tests. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, there is nothing indicating that a browser is automated by `selenium` as opposed to it being used by a real user. What you can do is to set a *specific custom cookie*, see:

- [Handling Cookies in Webdriver](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-cookies-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Figured as much, unfortunately there is an unexpected drawback to setting the cookie - it doesn't work for the first request. Not sure if the bug is in Codeception / Selenium / Facebook WebDriver / somewhere else. https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/766#issuecomment-115005827

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom user agent:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks